# Ember.js get data from controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller where I define the `TakenSeatNumbers` variable:

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectSeat: function(seat) {
    var orderTransaction = TravelClient.store.transaction();
    var takenSeatNumber = orderTransaction.createRecord(TravelClient.TakenSeatNumber, {number: seat.get('id')});
  }
});
```

How do I access `TakenSeatsNumbers` from the `tour/seats` template? The model `Tour` is in the context of `TourSeatsController`.

---

Comment: You can change this function variable a controller property so it is public. Declare it outside the `selectSeat` function and mark it as a property

Comment: no. you should do `takenSeatsNumber: null, selectSeat: function(seat) { ... }` and then from within `selectSeat` function you populate it like `this.set('takenSeatsNumber', orderTransaction....`, and in your template you render it as `{{takenSeatsNumber}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, promote that function variable (`takenSeatsNumber`) into a property within the controller so it's public, similar to the following:

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  takenSeatNumber: null, 
  selectSeat: function(seat) {
    var orderTransaction = TravelClient.store.transaction();
    this.set('takenSeatNumber', 
             orderTransaction.createRecord(TravelClient.TakenSeatNumber, {number: seat.get('id')})
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: By the way, what if I will need to get this data from another controller in future? How do the trick?

Comment: When you say get this data from another controller, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: How can I get access to `TakenSeatsNumber` records from order transaction from controller, different of `TourSeatsController`?

Comment: That's an `ObjectController`, so it pretty much acts as a *decorator* in Ember. It should be a property of `TourSeat` model. Simply *find* your model record and you should e able to access any public property or method defined in that controller